# how do you get each item in a scatterchart legend to appear only once

Tags: excel, vba, charts, duplicates, legend

The legend in my scatter chart shows a cluster for every point, I would like it to just show the unique items, and therefore it should only have 3 (A, B, C) not 6.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 series on your chart, each with 1 point I think (right click on the chart and click "Select data" and check how many series are there). What you need it 3 series: first and second one with 2 points and last one with 1 point.

Another option is to delete the repeating legend entries.

Comment: Hi Mitja thanks for your answer. Is there a programatic way of looping through the legend entries?

Comment: You can access the entries by `ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(1)`. There should be as many entries as there are series so I guess you could do a for loop over the number of series and delete the entries that repeat.